# Ruby class inheritance and arithmetic methods

Tags: ruby

I have this class in Ruby:

```
class Dollar < BigDecimal
  def initialize(val = 0)
    super val, 2
  end
end
```

However, the class reverts back to BigDecimal when I do an arithmetic operation.

```
irb(main):032:0> d = Dollar.new('5')
=> #<BigDecimal:7f12d787bf40,'0.5E1',9(18)>
irb(main):033:0> d.class
=> Dollar
irb(main):034:0> d += Dollar.new('9.99')
=> #<BigDecimal:7f12d786de18,'0.1499E2',18(36)>
irb(main):035:0> d.class
=> BigDecimal
```

How can I keep it being a `Dollar` after an arithmetic operation?

Comment: For those unfamiliar with `BigDecimal`, `require 'bigdecimal'` is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to redefine the arithmetic operations as well.

```
class Dollar < BigDecimal
  def + other; Dollar.new(super(other)) end
end
```

Comment: I'd have to do this for all arithmetic operations... Or rather, all methods that'd normally return BigDecimal.

Comment: Only for those that you want to return a `Dollar` instance.